# How to record only int value from html(php) to mysql database table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, int

My question is: How to insert number(int) to countTable when buttons are click?

Here is my sample code, Thank you.

HTML

```
<form action="check.php" method="POST">
  <button name="a">a</button>
  <button name="b">b</button>
  <button name="c">c</button>
</form>
```

check.php

```
require('connect.php');
$A = $_POST["a"];
$B = $_POST["b"];
$C = $_POST["c"];
$sql = "INSERT INTO countTable (numA,numB,numC)
VALUES(:numA,:numB,:numC)";
$pre = $conn->prepare($sql);

$pre->bindValue(':numA',$A);
$pre->bindValue(':numB',$B);
$pre->bindValue(':numC',$C);

$r = $pre->execute();
```

mysql countTable

```
create table countTable (
id varbinary(64) not null,
numA int(100),
numB int(100),
numC int(100),
primary key(id)
);
```

Comment: In what way is this code failing?

Comment: @David
when i click A button the error comes for the rest B and C button sth like this ->Notice: Undefined index....

Comment: a,b,c are not integers so trying to put them in to the integer field makes no sense

Comment: @Dagon
sorry Dagon i makes u confuse, ok what i wanna do is,i m developing event website and 'go' 'maybe' 'not' three button in my page. I want to know how many people go, maybe and not. And record the value to database.

Comment: That code is misleading.  Are you trying to give people 3 choices and insert their choice in the database?

Comment: if they can only pick one, you should use a radio list

Answer (score 1):

Buttons are used for creating events, not so much for capturing form input. You are not actually setting or capturing any values, so you should expect your POST vars to be empty anyway.

Based on what you are trying to accomplish, I would recommend the following:

```
<form action="check.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="A" />
    <input type="submit" value="A" />
</form>

<form action="check.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="B" />
    <input type="submit" value="B" />
</form>

<form action="check.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="C" />
    <input type="submit" value="C" />
</form>

//PHP side
$selected_value = $_POST['option'];

//... do more stuff
```

He we have 3 different forms, all with a hidden value representing. This hidden value will be sent via POST once the form is submitted.

Comment: thanks , i hope this may useful, but how to do if the value is not string="A",
i want int value, that int value is increase and record to table when i click the button

Comment: You will need to validate the value. Check out `filter_var()` and `is_numeric()` in the PHP docs